# Automatic installation not happening, when I click Run button

Tags: android, kotlin

When I click Run button in Android studio, the system fails to install the apk into emulator for the first time, if I manually installs the apk into emulator, then the second time onwards the apk installs, any one know the reason why first time the apk is not installing, throwing Error installing app, suggested action: Retry

When I run the app for the first time it should run due to this error I can't able check auto update option also!